# Binary values in C# verses SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, binary

I'm storing IP address values as binary values in SQL for this application. In SQL I convert an address to 3 digit zero padded values. So 1.2.3.4 would be 001.002.003.004 and then converted to binary. (0x001002003004)

In C# I can use System.Net.IPAddress.GetAddressBytes() to get the binary, and populate the database like this:

```
        cr.InsertInstitutionEntityIP(new InstitutionEntityIP
        {
            FromIP = Start.ToString(),//.Value,
            ToIP = IsRange ? End.ToString() : Start.ToString(),//.Value : Start.Value,
            IsActive = IsActive,
            InstitutionEntityID = institutionEntityID,
            DateEntered = DateTime.Now, 
            ToIPBinary = Start.GetAddressBytes(),
            FromIPBinary = End.GetAddressBytes()
        });
```

However, when I look at the database, it has stored like this: 0x01020304

What should I be doing in SQL to make sure my SQL conversion would match how C#'s GetAddressBytes will work?

Comment: Please show how you are padding the 0's and getting `0x001002003004`, using `System.Net.IPAddress.GetAddressBytes()` does not add the extra 0's for you and would return `0x01020304`, from what it looks like, `1.2.3.10` would be `0x001002003010` using your custom method, but `GetAddressBytes()` would return `0x0102030A`

Comment: `0x001 etc` 12 bit words? Usually binary data is stored by the 8bit byte.

Comment: The `0x` notation is hexadecimal.  The number 10 is `0xA`. 16 is `0x10`.  255, the maximum value for a byte, is `0xFF`.

You should store the addresses in SQL server using 8-hex-digit, not 12-hex-digit, values.

Comment: Yes, duh to me... I wasn't thinking clearly Friday afternoon. I needed to convert each segment to binary then combine. Sorry guys.